# How can I listen for when a notification occurs for my app and calendar app?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I want to be able to listen (BroadcastReceiver?) for whenever a notification occurs for my app and for the calendar app, even if the user doesn't interact with it and even if the screen is off.

I also want to be able to know when a user swipes away the notification.

I know that [AccessibilityEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html) can enable doing the first thing (listening for notifications) but it can't do the second one ([Cannot listen for notification dismissal](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18763)). Is there another way?

How would I do this? Can I at least have my app/listener called when my own notifications occur (they're for calendar events) and know that the notification is still in the notification tray?

Comment: You can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification

Comment: @bmavus Unfortunately, as I mention in my post, that will only handle the first part. That does not offer a way to know that a notification has been dismissed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631693/unable-to-receive-android-intent-action-event-reminder-broadcast but I am not sure how successful it is

Answer (score 1):

You can listen all the calendar notification info. How you say, you should use an AccessibilityService and switch the notification type. Then you get the package name an compare if it's from google calendar.

```
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    try {

        switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED:

            Log.d(LOG_SERVICE, "Click");

            break;
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED:

            Log.d(LOG_SERVICE, "Focused");

            break;
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED:

            Log.d(LOG_SERVICE, "Ihas been received a not" + type);

            String pack = (String) event.getPackageName();
                            if (pack.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google.android.calendar")) {
                   //The event information.
                    }
            break;

        default:
            type = "otro";
            Log.d(LOG_SERVICE, "otro");

            break;
        }

        AccessibilityNodeInfo notinfo = event.getSource();
        if (notinfo != null) {
            doSomethingWithNodeInfo(notinfo);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If the Android device is with ICS or more. You can use AccessibilityNodeInfo if the app developer design their notifications with accessibility.