# When calendar has fired receiver for reminder alerts in Android, how can I get the event id?

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
public class CalendarReminderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(CalendarContract.ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER)) {
        //Do Something Here to get EVENT ID
    }

}

}
```

Is there anyway to get the event id from the broadcast receiver for reminder events?
Here is my manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.calendar.CalendarReminderReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER" />
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: take look on this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631693/unable-to-receive-android-intent-action-event-reminder-broadcast

Comment: I have seen that thread.  It was my understanding that the individual could not even get his receiver to fire.  I have no problem with it firing.  I just don't know how to get the necessary data to ascertain the event id.  Thank you, though.

Comment: as mention in android docs here you can get Calender_ID 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#CALENDAR_ID

Comment: also take look on this thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018619/listen-to-android-calendar-changes-sync-delete-insert-etc

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am trying to get event_ID too.

Comment: anyone found solution? please let us know

Answer (score 6):

Maybe too late, but here is my solution:

```
if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(CalendarContract.ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER)) {
    //Do Something Here to get EVENT ID
    Uri uri = intent.getData();

    String alertTime = uri.getLastPathSegment();

    String selection = CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.ALARM_TIME + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.CONTENT_URI_BY_INSTANCE, new String[]{CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.EVENT_ID},selection,new String[]{alertTime}, null);

}
```

Comment: add this line: `if( cursor.moveToNext() )  eventId = cursor.getInt(0);`

Comment: working fine but not receiving calendar default notification now