# Is possible to get ID of new event added to calendar from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar, android-calendar

I want to get id of new event added to android calendar. I created a BroadcastReceiver but i cannot find any data in params.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32664925/4955934), it looks like achievable task. 
Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

**Manifest.xml**

```
     <receiver android:name=".controller.EventReceiver"
              android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:host="com.android.calendar"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
 class EventReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

    private val TAG = "BROADCAST_RECEIVER"

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        intent.action.logd(TAG)
        intent.data.logd(TAG)
        val uri = intent.data
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
  val filter = IntentFilter()
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED)
    filter.addDataScheme("content")
    filter.addDataAuthority("com.android.calendar", null)
    registerReceiver(EventReceiver(),filter)
```

Comment: Your `<intent-filter>` does not match the one in the linked question, and implicit broadcasts are generally banned on Android 8.0+ (so you will not receive this broadcast).

Comment: @CommonsWare I receive broadcast, i got logs from this class. I added code from activity